# mod_rewrite and referrer check, browser auto redirects when it shouldnt

Tags: .htaccess, caching, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a page on my website, call it B.html, which uses a referrer check via mod_rewrite.  If they are not coming from A.html, it will redirect them to A.html.

Starting from A, it works file.  They can link to B and view B. If they try to access B by typing the URL into the browser it redirects them to A as it should.

The issue is, if they come to the site through an external link, it will redirect them to A.html (as it should).  After this, if they click on the link to B from A, it forwards them back to A.

My first impression was that this was a cache issue, because if I close the browser and reopen it (or try in a private browser window) it links from A to B as it should.  I have tried adding this to both pages B and A:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

AND even this in my php code (not at the same time):

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
```

which I found from another post here, but that did not do the trick.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested I foudn my problem.  I was using 301 redirects in htaccess, so the broeser would auto cache the redirect.  It had nothing to do with the caching of the pages.